# Why self-contained Application?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am beginner in apache spark-scala, and I have been created a project with SBT (self-contained application).
 I searched on Internet and I asked many people, why we create the self-contained application on scala with SBT ? Why we need for self-contained application ? What is the interest of the self-contained application ?
 I arrived to these results:
- we create the self-contained application in scala with sbt to create an arborescence of project and we can run a full program.
- In the running of program we genere a file jar.

I run my program like this:

```
spark-submit --class "name_file" --master local[*] target/scala-2.11/"name_project"_2.11-1.0.jar
```

- With the self-contained application we can give my file jar to another person  and he can running my program without install spark or scala in another machine (like the files .dll in C++).

And finally, may be my question is not normaly, but I told, that I can ask my question in StackoverFlow and I am sure that I'll find the best answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name itself states that it have no external dependencies while running (not developing) it in production environments.

> A self-contained application consists of a single, installable bundle
>   that contains your application and a copy of the JRE or any Runtime
>   environment needed to run the application. When the application is
>   installed, it behaves the in the same way as any native application.

Read more from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/selfContainedApps/index.html)

And in you case a simple self contained application is [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications)

Comment: Did you mean when we run an application using Maven build tool ,it is not a self-contained.is it ?

Comment: @XlintXms, Not completely yes, until you never include any other external dependencies using maven in your application.